# How to create a link to a Facebook object within a comment using the Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I would like to be able to recreate the same comment linking ability that facebook has on their front end through the [graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (NOT [javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)).

For example, through the web interface I can type in @George... and then lookup one of my friends to link to in the comments.  See image below.

[image]

I have been able to POST comments using the API as documented [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).  This is pretty simple by just POSTing to /{POST_ID}/comments with a message parameter (you can try it out [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=POST_ID/comments)).

However, I have not found anywhere a doc to show how I can put in a link to another object within the comment post.  Has anyone done this with the Facebook API?

**NOTE:** I have tried what one person suggested and put in a simple link.  However as you can see from below, it does not give the nice formatted link of the user's name.

[image]

**UPDATE:** When I look what Facebook sends out on the form POST it looks like this

```
add_comment_text_text:post to Mark test
add_comment_text:post to @[4:Mark] test
```

but unfortunately, it looks like you can't post to the API in a similar manner (i.e. @[4:Mark]) and get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with the Facebook Graph API, only the Facebook website.  It has  been logged as a [feature request](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9441) though.